# Dockerfile command fails to copy a file

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

I'm trying to build [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/microservices-demo/blob/main/docs/development-guide.md) application locally (option 2) according to the provided tutorial. Source code is also there.

I'm using `skaffold run` command for it. Everything works fine but it fails on `adservice` `Dockerfile` line `22` with an error: `/bin/sh: 1: ./gradlew: not found`. This specific file can be found [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/microservices-demo/blob/main/src/adservice/Dockerfile).

I'm trying to debug it for last 3 hours with no success. Apparently cloning it in this specific way - `git clone https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/microservices-demo.git --config core.autocrlf=true` fixes the issue, but for me it changes nothing.

Edit

Changed EOL from windows to unix, still nothing.

Comment: seems like a bug https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/microservices-demo/issues/1347

Comment: @KeepCalmAndCarryOn yeah but I kind of need to resolve it, and I'm running out of ideas.

Comment: I think you need to find a copy of `gradlew` and gradle and copy them into the directory where you run the `docker build`

Comment: I see that those files are already there. Maybe add a `set -x` to the gradlew file to see why it's failing

Comment: @KeepCalmAndCarryOn I'm not exactly good at using docker just yet. Do you mean I should add `RUN gradlew set -x` just before `RUN ./gradlew installDist` (the line which fails).